# WordPress only apply funtion on front page

Tags: wordpress

I have put the below minimal PHP code in the `functions.php` and it works.

```
add_action( 'init', 'test' );

function test() {
   echo 'Testing...123';
}
```

But if I use `is_front_page()` to specify only apply this on the front page ( `front-page.php` ), then it won't work, why is that so?

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
   add_action( 'init', 'test' );

   function test() {
      echo 'Testing...123';
   }
}
```

Comment: In your WP settings, have you set a specific page to be a static front page? If not, `front-page.php` is never referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing it to the following

```
add_action( 'init', 'test' );

function test() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
      echo 'Testing...123';
   }
}
```